# Pandas how to calculate time since action in an app data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a database of userid, timestamp, action. Thousands of rows per userid over time. The action performed  can be login, invalid password, invalid login attempts.

I am trying to work out how the time it takes the user to login successfully after a failed login attempts. I'm not too sure how to even get started here.

I come from a SAS background and would use retain for something like that but how do I iterate over rows sorted by user ID and timestamp?

Sample Input

```
UserID  TimeStamp   Action
1   01/08/2020  Login Successful
1   01/08/2020  Login Successful
1   02/08/2020  Login Fail
1   02/08/2020  Login Fail
1   05/08/2020  Login Successful
2   01/08/2020  Login Successful
2   01/08/2020  Login Fail
2   09/08/2020  Login Fail
2   09/08/2020  Login Fail
2   10/08/2020  Login Successful
```

Sample Output

```
UserID  Difference between first login  fail and successful
1       3
2       9
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the output? Why the difference is 3 and 9?

Comment: is there no time component to your datetime? you won't be able to know for sure if someone logged in unsuccessfully or successfully on the same day - you can assume but there is no certainty

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def calcLoginTime(g):
    LoginFailTime = None
    for i, record in g.iterrows():
        if record['Action']=='Login Fail':
            if not LoginFailTime:
                LoginFailTime = record['TimeStamp']
            
            
        if record['Action'] == 'Login Successful':
            if LoginFailTime:
                df.loc[i, 'TimeAfterLoginFailMins'] = 24*60*(record['TimeStamp'].day - LoginFailTime.day) + (record['TimeStamp'] - LoginFailTime).seconds//60
                LoginFailTime=None
                
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(0, len(df))
df['TimeAfterLoginFailMins']=''
for i, UserAttepmts in df.groupby('UserID'):
    calcLoginTime(UserAttepmts.sort_values('TimeStamp', axis=0))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you what you are asking for.

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']) #convert to datetime
df = df.sort_values(by=['UserID','Timestamp'],ascending = (1,1)) #sort values
first = df.loc[df['Action'] == 'Login Fail'].groupby('UserID').first() #take the first fail
last = df.loc[df['Action'] == 'Login Successful'].groupby('UserID').last() #take the last success
dfdiff = last[['Timestamp']] - first[['Timestamp']] #subtract to get difference of dates
```

or

```
s = df.groupby('UserID')['Action'].transform(lambda x: (x.ne(x.shift()) & x.eq('Login Fail')).cumsum()).eq(1)
df.loc[s].groupby('UserID')['TimeStamp'].agg(lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()).days//30)
```

And this should work for multiple instances:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('UserID')['Action'].transform(lambda x: (x.ne(x.shift())))]
df2.groupby(['UserID',df2['Action'].eq('Login Fail').groupby(df2['UserID']).cumsum().where(lambda x: x.ge(1))])['TimeStamp'].agg(lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()).days//30)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if i wanted to do this for each instance of it happening? Would i have to use a function?